# Google sign in token usage

Tags: node.js, google-api, jwt, google-signin

I have a sign in button, which authenticates the user with google account.
By getting the token from google, I save it on a cookie, and authorize it with google from each server side call middleware. The expiration time is 1 hour. Is there a way to authenticate the user on each call, or I should generate my own JWT, with larger expire time?

Thanks